# ASP.NET date range constraint/validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

If I have a model that tracks employees request for holidays, how would I go about ensuring that an employee does not take multiple holidays within the same date range? Would this be handled with validation or creating a constraint in SQL Server? I used database first for this project.

```
 public partial class HolidayRequestForm
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

      [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime FinishDate { get; set; }

    [Range(0.0001, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Hours Requested must be greater than zero. ")]
    public decimal HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int YearCreated { get; set; }
    public int MonthCreated { get; set; }
    public int DayCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> YearOfHoliday { get; set; }


    [UIHint("Boolean.cshtml")]
    public Nullable<bool> Approved { get; set; }
    public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
    public string ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally I'd like that two employees can request the same date range but a single employee cannot request two holidays within the same date range. Could I use custom validation attribute maybe??

Comment: I think you can use custom validation there, which put as attribute for `DateTime` properties you want to validate. However you need to read other property value (e.g. `EmployeeID`) to achieve that.

Comment: This one is a business logic so go for a custom validation. Just check the requested start date and end date is in between your date range , and the requested dates are more than 1 then reject it with a message , may be if you want the details of these request then you can log it in your database for future reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given scenario is a business logic so it is better to implement this in your code itself instead of database constrains or triggers.

You can create a custom `validator` for the same and do a validation in the business layer. This approach will be easy maintainable/upgradable.

Use a normal method for validation , or create custom ValidationAttribute by inhering `ValidationAttribute` and by overriding `IsValid` method.